# Transpositions and the identity permutation

Tags: permutations

Prove that $\sigma^2$=$\epsilon$ if and only if $\sigma$ can be expressed as a product of disjoint 2-cycles. $\epsilon$ denotes the identity permutation.

Any hints to help me get started would be really appreciated!

Comment: Consider that for a permutation $\sigma$, $\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(x_n))=x_n$ implies, since also $\sigma(\sigma(x_n))=x_n$, implies that $\sigma=\sigma^{-1}$.  Can you understand then what that means for the elements of the set being permuted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  I assume you already know that any permutation is a product of disjoint cycles.  Now suppose that one of these cycles is
$$(\,a_1\ a_2\ \cdots\ a_n\,)$$
with $n\ge3$.  Then
$$\sigma^2(a_1)=\sigma(a_2)=a_3\ne a_1$$
and so $\sigma^2$ is not the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a permutation $\sigma$ and elements $x_i, x_j, x_k$.  If you assume that $\sigma^2=\epsilon$, then that means that
$$\sigma^2(x_i)=x_i$$

Now consider that $\sigma$ sends $x_i$ to $x_j$ and sends $x_j$ to $x_k$.  Thus

$$x_i=\sigma^2(x_i)=\sigma(\sigma(x_i))=\sigma(x_j)=x_k$$

Therefore we can represent this permutation as $(x_i\ x_j\,)$. As every other element $x_m, x_n$ have these properties, we have disjoint 2-cycles or we have 1-cycles for the condition that $\sigma_m=\sigma_n$.